# Cannot convert value of type '(User?, Error?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'AuthDataResultCallback?'

Tags: swift, firebase

When I update firebase pods get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(User?, Error?) -> ()' to expected argument type 'AuthDataResultCallback?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional, Optional) -> ()>')

```
static func signUp(username: String, email: String, User: String, Phone: String ,password: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError:  @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user: User?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            onError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you try `Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { user, error in` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just write closure without type definition.

**Updated code:**

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { user, error in
    ...
}
```

Comment: fixed but get new error >Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid'

Comment: @felon I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376331/value-of-type-authdataresult-has-no-member-uid) question will help you

Comment: @felon If my answer helped you fix your error - please accept and vote

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
static func signUp(username: String, email: String, User: String, Phone: String ,password: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void, onError:  @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { user, error in
        if error != nil {
            onError(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        let uid = user?.uid
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("profile_image").child(uid!)

        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

             self.setUserInfomation(profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl!, username: username, Phone: Phone,email: email,User:User, uid: uid!, onSuccess: onSuccess)
        })
    })
}
```